# An error occurred while publishing Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

When i am publishing site in Sitecore it is giving error.

> Job started: Publish to 'web'|#Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.FormatException: Unrecognized Guid format.

Please guide me how can i resolve this error.

Comment: Can you access the log files and give more of the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Did you an upgrade recently? If so, maybe this will help:

http://reasoncodeexample.com/2015/03/26/sitecore-linkdatabase-unrecognized-guid-format/

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild the Link Database, gives that an error.

With Sql server Profiler (from SQL server Management Studio) you can find the item with the issue. Create a filter to capture the Web database. Start the publish, and press pause when the error occur. Now you see the latest publish action and can you see the guid in the query.

This is described here: [Upgrade Sitecore experience with modules](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/upgrade-and-modules.aspx)
In this case the issue was in the Webforms For Marketers (WFFM) module, the Tracking Field.

Also look for broken links. (Press right mouse button on the left white space in the content editor to choice with icons you want to see)